# Interest of using glPolygonMode OpenGL command

Tags: polygon, opengl-sc

When reading the specification of `glPolygonMode()`, I have the feeling that it is just an alternative way to fill a polygon with the desired color.

Am I right?

Because if yes, what is the benefit of using this command to fill a polygon, rather than just using `glVertex()` commands which fills the polygon by doing the interpolation between the specified polygon vertices?

I am using OpenGL SC 1.0.1.

Comment: No. [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) sets a mode, it controls the interpretation of polygons for rasterization. The default `glPolygonMode` is `GL_FILL`. Alternatively it can be set to `GL_LINE` or `GL_POINT`. –

Comment: ok, what do you mean by "interpolation of polygons for rasterization" ? Which properties of the polygon are interpolated ?

Comment: Please read [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml)

Comment: well, I read that but I am very confused. I am not sure to understand rasterization...
Do we have like a default rasterization mode in OpenGL SC 1.0.1 ?

Comment: "Interpretation", not "interpolation".  If the mode isn't `GL_FILL`, polygons don't get filled at all, they just have the edges or vertices drawn.

Comment: Is there another way to control interpretation of polygons rather than using glPolygonMode ?